# Avianca Lifemiles Round the World Award Redemption

Tags: loyalty-programs, avianca

Does Avianca Airlines (thru Lifemiles) offer a Round the World Award like Krisflyer/Singapore Airlines? Something similar to Oneworld's Multicarrier Award Ticket. If so, could you send a link to the award charts?

Comment: I am not getting the link. I propose that you visit the Avianca Lifemiles website or contact their customer service department directly. They can offer you with the most recent information as well as any accessible award charts.